# How do i extract an array in an array to get another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

How do I extract the array in an array and structure it to be one whole array?

Input:

```
const input = [{
    categoryName: "Chinese food",
    tabs: [{
        header: "Chicken Rice",
        content: "Hainanese chicken rice is a dish of poached chicken and seasoned rice"
      },
      {
        header: "Dim sum",
        content: "large range of small Chinese dishes that are traditionally enjoyed in restaurants"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categoryName: "Italian food",
    tabs: [{
      header: "Pizza",
      content: "Dish of Italian origin consisting of a usually round"
    }]
  },
]
```

Output (Need to extract all the headers out to become this array)

```
const output = [
  {
    "categoryName": "Chinese food",
    "header": "Chicken Rice",
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Chinese food",
    "header": "Dim sum",
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Italian food",
    "header": "Pizza"
  },
]
```

tried this but i can't seem to add categoryName inside

```
const getHeadersWithId = arr => (
  arr.flatMap(                    // iterate over 'input' array and 'flat'-ten the result
    ({tabs}) => (tabs.map(        // de-structure 'tabs' & iterate over it
      ({header}) => ({header})    // de-structure 'header' & retain it to intermediate-result array
    ))
  ).map(
    ({header}, idx) => ({         // iterate with index 'idx'
      id: idx+1,                  // generate the 'id' and store
      header                      // header from intermediate-result array element
    })
  )
);
```

This is what I got when I run this chunk of code

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "header": "Chicken Rice"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "header": "Dim sum"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "header": "Pizza"
  }
]
```

Comment: What are your ideas about this? What have you tried

Comment: Hi @TusharShahi, I tried the code above. Updated the question to include what I tried.

Comment: If you only want `categoryName` and `header`, what's the the `id` property in your code?

Comment: TL;DR on the duplicate? You want `input.flatMap(({ categoryName, tabs }) => tabs.map(({ header }) => ({ categoryName, header })))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `map()` in my opinion. Just use the `categoryName` and pass it into your inner `map()`.

Building up on your code:

```js
const input = [{
    categoryName: "Chinese food",
    tabs: [{
        header: "Chicken Rice",
        content: "Hainanese chicken rice is a dish of poached chicken and seasoned rice"
      },
      {
        header: "Dim sum",
        content: "large range of small Chinese dishes that are traditionally enjoyed in restaurants"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categoryName: "Italian food",
    tabs: [{
      header: "Pizza",
      content: "Dish of Italian origin consisting of a usually round"
    }]
  },
]

const getHeadersWithId = arr => (
  arr.flatMap(                    // iterate over 'input' array and 'flat'-ten the result
    ({tabs,categoryName}) => tabs.map(       // de-structure 'tabs' & iterate over it
      ({header}) => ({header,categoryName})    // de-structure 'header' & retain it to intermediate-result array
    )
  )
);

console.log(getHeadersWithId(input));
```

Comment: Yes correct. Just copy pasted OP's code. Editing